# 2 examples of molar volumes of binary mixtures

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, volume

It‘s about the following task:

Figure: 2 examples of molar volumes of binary (2 components, i=A,B is the component index).
mixtures. Let V be the total volume of the mixture.
Using binary mixture as an example, explain/ define the molar volumes m, i, and
^E (excess). How can you read these quantities from the graph?

[image]

I really have no clue how to proceed here. I've been dealing with the task all day, but I still don't understand it. I have also watched countless videos about it, but none of them helped me.
How can I read from the graph what Vm, vi and V^E are? I need a brief theoretical explanations of these things. I would be very glad if someone could help me further because I struggled the whole day with this task.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of partial molar quantities?

Comment: Do you know the equation for the molar volume of an ideal binary liquid solution in terms of the molar volumes of the pure components?

Comment: And ideal solutions vs regular solutions?

Comment: @ChetMiller, yes I'm familiar with it but I have no clue how to explain it theoretically. I only know the equation but I don't know the meaning of it. Everything was mathematically explained to us all the time, which is why I have difficulties to understand and solve this task.

Comment: @Jon Custer, i only know that solutions are ideal when there is no interaction between the solvents.

Comment: Right, so how about regular solutions, and excess enthalpies of mixing which appear to be analogous to the excess volume of mixing here?

Comment: regular solutions have interaction, the molecules interact randomly with each other. Excess enthalpies occur when you mix the enthalpy of two components/solvents  together, I think. All these components have an ethalpy and the sum of the enthalpies of component A and component B describes the excess enthalpy, it's the difference. And excess volume can be described the same. When you mix the solution A and the solution B together, the volume changes. It also describes the difference. I described it theoretically because the equations didn't help me to understand it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal solution, the molar volume of the solution is a weighted average (in terms of mole fractions) of the molar volumes of the pure components at the same temperature and pressure as the mixture:  $$V^{ID}=V^0_Ax_A+V^0_Bx_B=V^0_A+(V^0_B-V^0_A)x_B$$The excess molar volume is equal to the actual molar volume minus the ideal molar volume:  $$V^{EX}=V_m-V^{ID}$$or$$V_m=V^{ID}+V^{EX}$$

Comment: Alright, thank you for the equations but how should I read these quantities from the graph? I have difficulties to understand the meaning of these equations. What do these quantities explain? Where on the graph are they? How can I read these quantities from the graph and why?

Comment: The questions you are asking involve Middle-School math (elementary algebra), not Physics.  Didn't. they teach this to you in Middle School, how to plot a straight line and get the intercepts?

Comment: The straight dashed lines are for the ideal solution behavior.

Comment: I found it after I posted my question. I solved it now.

Comment: But there are other questions like: Are there areas with negative partial volumes, if so, where (which of the mapped 
mixtures, which component, which areas)? Is this possible at all with the volume of mixtures? How should I proceed here? Schould I draw a tangent line?

Comment: Yes, you draw tangent lines to the Vm curve.  The intercepts at xB=0 and xB=1 are the partial molar volumes.

Comment: I posted the pic again with the tangent lines (above). Is that correct?

Comment: No. The tangent lines should be drawn at any arbitrary points along the curve, and the intercepts will be the partial molar volumes corresponding to each specific point.

Comment: I draw the tangent lines again. Is it correct now?

Comment: Those lines are not tangent.  Do you know the definition of the word tangent?

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't understand exactly what you mean by drawing at any arbitrary points along the curve. Please apologize, I'm asking again but I didn't capture it yet.

Comment: Just pick a point along the curve and draw a tangent straight line to the curve at that point , with the line running from x=0 to x=1.

Comment: Okay, I did it. I hope it‘s correct now.

Comment: Ok.  Now indicate the partial molar volumes on the figure, corresponding to that particular point on the curve.

Comment: It is the first derivative, so it is then (Vm/dx) ? But I think I have to be more specific. Actually it describes the difference, so it should be anything like (Vm/dx) = V2 - V1. But I'm not sure 100%

Comment: The partial molar volumes are the intercepts.

Comment: Yes, but the equation? isn't it correct ? What shoud I mend here?

Comment: You need to get the equation for the tangent line.  I will submit another answer to show you how to get that.

Comment: All right, thank you! But I would like to know how to figure it out on the graph without any equation

Comment: You just draw a tangent line at your selected point.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know which area is negative?? How do I know it graphically?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the equation for the tangent line.  The starting equations are $$[V_m]_{x=x_0}=(1-x_0)[V_A]_{x=x_0}+x_0[V_B]_{x=x_0}$$and$$\left[\frac{dV_m}{dx}\right]_{x=x_0}=[V_B]_{x=x_0}-[V_A]_{x=x_0}$$where $x=x_0$ is the point of tangency and $[V_A]_{x=x_0}$ and $[V_B]_{x=x_0}$ are the partial molar volumes at $x=x_0$.  So, using the point-slope formula for the equation of a straight line, we have the equation of the tangent line as $$V=[V_m]_{x=x_0}+\left[\frac{dV_m}{dx}\right]_{x=x_0} (x-x_0)$$

Combining the previous equations, the equation for the tangent line is $$V=(1-x)[V_A]_{x=x_0}+x[V_B]_{x=x_0}$$This indicates that the partial molar volumes of A and B at the specified tangent point are equal to the intercepts of the tangent line at x = 0 and x = 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have further questions. Is there a negative VL in any of the mixtures? If so, in which areas? Can this be at all?

Comment: For that I need to draw a tangent line, but how do I know if it‘s negative? How should I show this graphically?

Comment: The intercepts of the tangent line are the partial molar volumes.

Comment: Yes, but how do I figure out if they are graphically negative?

Comment: I mean in which areas on the graph is V_l (the partial molar volume) negative ?